# How to deprecate a field in a Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I have a data class representing a user. One of the fields is `age`, but we want to change it into the more robust `birthday`. For migration purposes, I want to deprecate the usage of one of the fields in the data class. I intuitively wrote:

```
data class User(
    val name:String,
    val type: UserType,

    @Deprecated(
        "New: Duration of validity should be expressed in period and periodUnit",
        level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING
    )
    val age: Int,

    val birthDay: ZonedDateTime
)
```

However, the `@Deprectated` annotation is not picked up because according to the documentation it is only applicable to CLASS, FUNCTION, PROPERTY, ANNOTATION_CLASS, CONSTRUCTOR, PROPERTY_SETTER, PROPERTY_GETTER, TYPEALIAS.

Is there a nice/clever way to keep this class a dataclass, but mark the `age` field deprecated?

Comment: What are you looking for in terms of compatibility? Do you want source compatibility to support calls to the old constructor? References to the old `age` property? Binary compatibility with former constructor calls or property references? Do you (de)serialize this class and want to stay compatible with the serialized format? This would change how to approach this

Comment: Ideally I'd like the age field to be `age: Int? = null` so that calls to the constructor will work, regardless if the caller fills in age or not. After everybody removed the reference to the age field, it can then be safely removed from the User class.
For more context; I'd like to do this because it is a multi-module project with a big development team, and I don't want to change too many lines, or break too much work in progress.

Comment: The deprecation you wrote works fine for me. `age` is a property, which is one of the valid targets you mentioned.

Comment: *so that calls to the constructor will work* - this is sufficient for source compatibility, but not for binary compatibility, hence my question. Calls to the constructor from already compiled code will not work even with a default parameter value. You have to be precise in your requirements here

Comment: In my case, source compatibility is sufficient, so that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deprecated the field, but I'm guessing what you mean that "it's not picked up" is that the field is not marked deprecated when you initialize the class. In that case, the field is actually a constructor argument so you need to deprecate *the constructor* so the class can't be initialized with that argument:

```
class UserType
fun ZonedDateTime.toAge() = 0 // To convert a birthday to an age

data class User @Deprecated(           // Mark primary constructor deprecated
  "Use Birthday constructor instead",
  level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING
) 
constructor(
  val name : String,
  val type : UserType,
  @Deprecated(
    "New: Duration of validity should be expressed in period and periodUnit",
    level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING
  )
  val age : Int,
  val birthDay : ZonedDateTime
) {
  constructor( // Create secondary constructor that omits age
    name : String,
    type : UserType,
    birthDay : ZonedDateTime
  ) : this(name, type, birthDay.toAge(), birthDay)
}
```

In Android Studio / Intellij it looks like this:

[image]

And with deprecating the field itself you get the deprecation warning on the field access:

[image]

Once all uses of the original constructor are not used, you can delete `age` and the secondary constructor.